# VB.NET Absolutely strange form load behaviour

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, right-to-left

I am experiencing a strange behaviour when using RightToLayout layout:
My form automatically closes.

I have created a simple project to reproduce the problem:

Create a new VB.NET project in VS2012 and add forms "Form1" and "Form2" to it.
Set "Form1" to be the start form.

Then add the following code to "Form1":

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.Hide()

        Dim f As New Form2
        f.ShowDialog()

        MessageBox.Show("After dialog closed.")

        modControls.setFormRTL(Me) 'This line causes the Form2 to automatically close. Why??? This line should only be processed AFTER the dialog has been shown and closed

    End Sub
End Class
```

Add the following code to "Form2":

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        modControls.setFormRTL(Me)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Add a module with the name "modControls" to the project.
Add the following code to it:

```
Module modControls

    Public Sub setFormRTL(ByVal uForm As Form)

        uForm.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes

    End Sub

End Module
```

Without the setFormRTL, my project works perfectly fine, but with it, "Form2" automatically closes down. You can see this because the messagebox is shown.

When I remove the line

```
        modControls.setFormRTL(Me)
```

from Form1 load, it works fine again. 
Yes, I really mean from "Form1", not from "Form2"!!!

Now this is really strange because it should not matter at all because this line is not processed before the dialog is closed.
I hope somebody understands what I mean.

Can anybody shed some light on what might be happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll get unexpected behavior if you set the `RightToLeft` property anywhere other than a control's constructor (in VB.NET parlance, that's the `New` method).

In fact, the constructor is where you should set *all* of the properties of a form or control object. If you come from VB 6, it might seem logical to do it in the `Load` event handler, but that's not idiomatic .NET and, as you've discovered, can cause problems when initializing certain properties.

The technical reason for this is that certain properties (like `RightToLeft`) can actually only be set on the native window (which is how the `Form` objects used in the .NET world are implemented behind the scenes) at the time that it is created. When you attempt to change the property, the framework code actually has to destroy and then re-create the native window with the new property values.

Change the code to look like this instead:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        modControls.SetFormRtl(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Hide()

        Dim f As New Form2
        f.ShowDialog()

        MessageBox.Show("After dialog closed.")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        modControls.SetFormRtl(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

Speaking of non-idiomatic .NET code:

1. Methods should all be Pascal cased by convention. That means your `setFormRTL` method should be named `SetFormRtl`.
2. A helper function that sets the properties of an object just seems wrong to me. If anything, that's just bad OO design. If you want this method to be available for all of your `Form` objects, derive a custom form class and add this method (or even do the desired initialization in the constructor). Either way, all forms that you derive from this custom form object will inherit the functionality. Example:

   ```
   Public Class MyCustomForm : Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

       Public Sub New()
           MyBase.New()

           Me.SetRtl()
       End Sub

       Public Sub SetRtl()
           Me.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
       End Sub

   End Class

   Public Class Form1 : Inherits MyCustomForm

       Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
           Me.Hide()

           Dim f As New Form2
           f.ShowDialog()

           MessageBox.Show("After dialog closed.")
       End Sub

   End Class

   Public Class Form2 : Inherits MyCustomForm

       Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

       End Sub

   End Class
   ```

Comment: +1 But actually `setFormRTL` should be named `SetFormRtl` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Comment: Indeed... I always forget that after working on a project where that particular convention was explicitly not followed. Force of habit, I suppose. Updated my answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Can you suggest something for the following scenario? I am using the application framework and thus I have a start form. But in the main form's "New" event, I don't know yet if the user has chosen a RTL languge for my application, so I can not set it there yet. I am evaluating it in the form load event. Should I simply stuff the RTL evaluation into the New event?

Comment: @tmighty Yes, the detection code still goes in the constructor (i.e. the New method). Determining whether your form should be RTL is as simple as checking the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft` property. That will return information about the language settings currently in use.

Comment: @CodyGray In my application, the user can select a different language. I am storing the selected language in a database, so I also need to do the database opening in the New constructor. Is this perfectly fine, or should the New constructor only be used for "simple stuff" and not such heavy things like DB opening?

Comment: @tmighty Yes, it should still be done in the constructor. Everything you would otherwise have planned to do in the `Load` event handler should be done in the constructor. The only difference is the form hasn't been created yet. Of course, there might be even better ways to do it, looking at the big architectural picture. For example, you might query this information from the database at application startup and set a global/`Shared` property that is read/inherited by *all* forms created by your application. But I don't know to what extent you want to redesign your app, or just make it work. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you. For now, I would like to just may it work. I have a Settings.Language.LCID struct that holds the language variable (once received from the database). This struct is located in a public module, so I can access it from anywhere. Is that not fine?

Comment: Since Form1 already inherits from Form, why not just place the line `Me.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes` in the constructor?  What purpose does the `MyCustomForm` class serve?  Is it just to avoid having to set the `RightToLeft` for each form?

Comment: @Chris I'm assuming that the `SetRtl` method (`setFormRTL` in the original code) does some other work and it's been simplified merely for clarity when asking the question. Otherwise you're right.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this? all i am doing here is setting the RTL before the form is displayed.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Me.Hide()

        Dim f As New Form2
        modControls.setFormRTL(f)
        f.ShowDialog()

        MessageBox.Show("After dialog closed.")

        modControls.setFormRTL(Me)

    End Sub
End Class
```

and remove code form load event of form 2

Comment: Wow, this works, even if I do not remove the code from Form2's load event. But I really need to know why. Do you have any ideas?? I thought that the Form Load event was the right place to do that. I would really like to do it somewhere inside the Form, not from "outside" as in your example.

Comment: Also, I am not sure how I can set the RightToLeftLayout property even before the form's handle was created.